# "Invalid class typecast" when loading stream from SQLite (delphi)

Tags: sqlite3, delphi-xe8, stream

Estou a tentar buscar uma imagem que já inseri na minha base de dados SQlite, no entanto na linha

```
ms:=query.CreateBlobStream(query.FieldByName('imagem'),TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
```

tenho o erro  "Invalid class typecast"

nota: Estou a utilizar delphi-xe8;

Aqui está o meu codigo:

```
    Procedure Tform33.LoadFromSQLiteBlobArt;
       var
              ms:TStream;
              BlobField:Tblobfield;
              i:integer;
            begin
           try
            query.SQL.Text:='SELECT imagem From Artigos where Imagem>0;';
            query.open;
             query.First;
              num_regs_fb_art:=0;
               while not query.Eof do
                 begin
                  i:=i+1;
                   try

                     query.MaxBlobSize:=100;
                     BinaryAsBITMap[i]:=Tbitmap.create;
                     ms:=TMemoryStream.create;

                     query.FieldByName('imagem').SetFieldType(ftBlob);

                     ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);

                //ms:=query.CreateBlobStream(query.FieldByName('imagem'),bmRead);
         ms:=query.CreateBlobStream(query.FieldByName('imagem'),TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
                     BinaryAsBITMap[i].LoadFromStream(ms);

                     image1.Bitmap:=BinaryAsBITMap[i];

                   finally
                     ms.Free;
                   end;
                  query.Next;
                  end;
             except
             on e:exception do
             showmessage(e.Message);
             end;
             query.Close;
           end;
```

encontrei onde estava o erro, a final o problema não era o codigo. O proprio campo na base de dados está do tipo LargeINT. 
Porque está como referido é um mistério, pois o criei como BLOB. Se encontrar uma solução postarei aqui.

nota: fiz isso para descobrir o tipo do campo:

```
ShowMessage(query.FieldByName('imagem').ClassName);
```